# Iptables rules or other way to intentionally delay a packet for 5 seconds before accepting it

Tags: iptables

Would like to keep an executable in a suspended state and only resume it when a packet arrives. One way to do it would be to add an iptables rule that writes to the log and a script that polls the log and when it detects a new log entry it resumes the executable. This would fail the first time a packet arrives but work the second time. Can the first packet be delayed for 5 seconds using iptables rules, in order to give the script a chance to resume the executable before the packet is passed to it?

The resume would be done as follows:

```
kill -CONT $PID_OF_PROCESS
```

The suspend would be done as follows when nothing appears in the log for a while:

```
kill -TSTP $PID_OF_PROCESS
```

Comment: You mean as in "iptables rule to log", then delay 5 seconds, then deliver packet again? AFAIK you can only add delays with `tc` in the queeing discipline, so you'd probably need a second "loopback" interface somehow... doesn't look straightforward.

Comment: Iptables rule to log, then delay 5 seconds, then deliver the packet. Maybe a duplicate of the packet if necessary. Or something completely different not using iptables at all.

Comment: What about the `nflog` extension to forward the packet to a userspace process listening on some multicast group? The userspace process can wake up the executable, disable the iptables rule, and if it's a TCP connection, on retransmit the now resumed executable should be able to process the packet. On suspend, activate the iptables rule again.

Comment: Traffic to delay is coming from another server. We want to delay AFTER we detect incoming traffic and resume the executable. EDIT: now I saw your nflog comment. Sounds good.

Comment: Yes, I meant: Do the delay in the userspace program if you want to re-inject the packet, and don't want to wait for the retry in the TCP connection.